# Database Link creates more than 1 session

Tags: database, oracle, session, plsql, sqlplus

We have two Oracle databases
1. 11.2.0.4
2. 12.1.0.2
We create a Dblink from_11_to_12.
I connect via sqlplus to both databases and issue the commands below, step-by-step, first at 12c , second at 11g and so on:

At 12c

```
SQL> select sid,serial# from v$session where username = 'REP'; --Step 1
no rows selected
SQL> select sid,serial# from v$session where username = 'REP';  --Step 3
SID    SERIAL#                                                           
---------- ----------                                                           
    11      53421                                                           
    17      28325                                                           
    37      22230                                                           
   453      23175                                                           
   462      48252                                                           

SQL> select sid,serial# from v$session where username = 'REP'; --Step 5
   SID    SERIAL#                                                           
---------- ----------                                                           
    11      53421                                                           
    17      28325                                                           
   378      55283                                                           
   453      23175                                                           
   462      48252                                                           

SQL> select sid,serial# from v$session where username = 'REP'; --Step 7

   SID    SERIAL#                                                           
---------- ----------                                                           
    11      53421                                                           
    17      28325                                                           
   378       2986                                                           
   453      23175
```

at 11g

```
SQL> select id from table1@from_11_to_12 where rownum <1;  --Step 2
no rows selected
SQL> commit; --Step 4
Commit complete.
SQL> alter session close database link from_11_to_12; --Step 6
Session altered.
```

As you can see even after Step 6, still there are session at remonte database.
And more than that, why the connection creates 5 sessions?

How can I close those remote sessions. We work with shared servers, so if many people connect at the same time there will be at least 4 sessions busy.

Comment: Not sure but I think the database maintains a connection pool so the sessions won't necessarily disappear from v$session straight away. Check whether they are active or not.

Comment: what happens if you open more sessions from 11g like the first? how many sessions you will see in 12c when they are open and after their closure?

Comment: I think I've solved the issue. I've recreated the dblink without using SHARED option, just PUBLIC. I opens starts just 1 session at the remote DB and closes it when issuing the close database link.

Comment: It would be nice if you elaborate an answer to your question with what you've learned, the solution, etc.

Comment: This paragraph from the documentation made me change the DBlink: `'Shared database links are not useful in all situations. Assume that only one user accesses the remote server. If this user defines a shared database link and 10 shared server processes exist in the local database, then this user can require up to 10 network connections to the remote server. Because the user can use each shared server process, each process can establish a connection to the remote server.'